# Two dimensional matrix-like data type using lists and/or mutable lists

Tags: array, scheme, matrices, racket

I am trying to think of an implementation of a two dimensional matrix-like data type.
Normally I would take an array of arrays but I'm bound to a relatively low language level which only provides lists and mutable lists, because this is part of (but not an exercise itself, I could simply use an inefficient solution) a software project at university. In this, we are only allowed to use a specific language level.
So of cause I could take a list of mutable lists and, in search of an item in *row n* and *column m*, get the *m-th* mutable list and go throught it until position *n*. But isn't there a better solution than going through the whole list?

Comment: Do you want just to put/retrieve elements with certain indexes? Are there any other requirements or use cases, like searching by value?

Comment: No, just put/retrieve. Forgot to mention that.

Comment: And one more question: does it have to be constant size or resizable? Like you create it without specifying the size, and then you put elements it just automatically allocates the space.

Comment: The size can stay the same after creation.

Comment: I would think that lists are a higher level language feature. At the lowest level, memory is just a flat set of memory locations that are read/written by specifying the addresses of the locations. 1-d arrays are a fairly simple abstraction over that memory space. Lists are a more complex abstraction beyond arrays.

Comment: Ok, sorry. By "low language level" I don't mean "near machine level" but a level where I can only use the base functionality of a language and not much more. And in Racket/Scheme the base functionality is just _cons_, _first_, _rest_ and some condition and lambda stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need constant size, and access elements by their indexes, I'd say go with 1-dimensional array of `WIDTH*HEIGHT` size. You can just translate indexes like `matrix[x+y*WIDTH]` or build a wrapper class to do it like `matrix.get(x, y)` - that way you don't have to track width, and you can add boundary checks.

Access by index will have a constant time (`O(1)`) performance.

Comment: That is pretty clever, thanks. But the problem is that I don't have arrays, but only (mutable) lists, which only can be accessed via _first_ and _rest_. So I'd need to go through the whole list in worst case.

Comment: Than maybe there is a better solution. What language is it?

Comment: It's Racket/Scheme.

Comment: @Benjoyo: Racket has Vectors, which behave similarly to non-resizeable arrays: http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/vectors.html

Comment: @poke yes, but I'm bound to lists.

Comment: I think maybe a search tree would be good?

Comment: @Benjoyo: I'm really curious now. Can you edit your answer to explain why you are bound to lists?

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: I solved it using a balanced binary search tree whose nodes are pairs of the index (calculated with the formula above) and the data to store.